# Jersey2 Client OutOfMemoryError when uploading large file

Tags: java, jersey, out-of-memory, jax-rs, jersey-client

I am working on fileupload using below code but while uploading more than 300 MB file, I am getting OutOfMemoryError.

Here's my code below

```
package com.actifio.service.foresight;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Entity;
import javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataMultiPart;
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPartFeature;
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.file.FileDataBodyPart;

public class UploadFileTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        final Client client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder()
                .register(MultiPartFeature.class).build();

        final FileDataBodyPart filePart = new FileDataBodyPart("file",
                new File("C:/temp/sample.pdf"));
        FormDataMultiPart formDataMultiPart = new FormDataMultiPart();
        final FormDataMultiPart multipart = (FormDataMultiPart) formDataMultiPart
                .field("foo", "bar").bodyPart(filePart);

        final WebTarget target = client
                .target("http://localhost:8080/JerseyDemos/rest/upload/pdf");
        final Response response = target.request().post(
                Entity.entity(multipart, multipart.getMediaType()));

        // Use response object to verify upload success

        formDataMultiPart.close();
        multipart.close();
    }
}
```

But I am getting  Java heap space Exception, check below for more details

```
javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: Java heap space
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.invoke(ClientRuntime.java:263)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$1.call(JerseyInvocation.java:671)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$1.call(JerseyInvocation.java:668)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:228)
at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:444)
at
```

Can anyone help me on this issue?

Comment: What is the value of your maximum Java heap size? What are you doing with the file in your server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [chunks](https://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/1.17/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/client/Client.html#setChunkedEncodingSize(java.lang.Integer)) and streams:

```
@POST
@Path("/upload")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response uploadFile(FormDataMultiPart formDataMultiPart) {
     FormDataBodyPart filePart = formDataMultiPart.getField("file");         
     InputStream fileInputStream = filePart.getValueAs(InputStream.class);
     .
     .
     .
}
```